# Redux-toolkit & React-redux store typing issue - Types of property 'store' are incompatible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to set up a fresh react project with redux-toolkit.
I am using React: 17.0.2, @reduxjs/toolkit: 1.6.2 and react-redux: 7.2.6

Facing typescript issue when trying to configure the store. I don't have any reducer code yet just an empty store.

The type of configured store does not match with the store type to be provided to react-redux.

The **error** I am getting is :

[ts]
Types of property 'store' are incompatible.
Type 'EnhancedStore<any, any, any[]>' is not assignable to type 'Store<any, AnyAction>'.
Property 'getState' is missing in type 'EnhancedStore<any, any, any[]>'.[image]

Below is my store.ts file

```
    import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'; 
           
    const store = configureStore({
        reducer: {} 
    });
    
    export default store;
```

Below is my app.tsx file

> ```
> import * as React from 'react';
> import TestComponent from './components/TestComponent';
> import store from './stores';
> import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
> import { History } from 'history';
>
> interface AppComponentProps {
>     history: History;
> }
>
> export default ({ history }: AppComponentProps) => {
>   return (
>       <Provider store={store}>
>         <TestComponent />
>       </Provider>
>   );
> };
> ```

Could it be due to wrong versions or I am configuring it wrong way ? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you make sure that you do not accidentally have redux 4.0.5 and 4.1.x both in your node_modules?

Comment: @phry : I checked, I have only version 4.1.0 of redux installed in my node modules

Comment: Hmm. Is this also occuring when you add an actual reducer?

Comment: @phry Yes, I just added a small sample reducer for counter. This error still shows up

Comment: This should not happen. But I fear unless you link a GitHub repo or CodeSandbox to show off the problem, it will not really be possible to help you.